# how to render radio button dynamically in a table?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am new in mvc5. I am facing a problem is that i want to render some row in a table with a radio button in every row. If i clicked or checked the radio button then it will show a picture in that row. Now the problem is that, i am trying to test every row by clicking but the result is only one row showing alert and this is only first row. where is the problem i don't know? will you please help me to find out the problem?

```
@if (Model != null) { 
foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr style="vertical-align:middle">
        <td style="vertical-align:middle">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CandId)
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align:middle">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CandName)
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align:middle">
            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Position, new {id="ps" })
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align:middle">
            <img src="/Ballot/RetrieveImage/@item.id" alt="" height=50 width=50/>
            @*@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.cand_symbol)*@
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align:middle; text-align:center;">
           @Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem => item.isCandidate, item.CandId, new { id="rd",name="rd"})
            <img src="" height="50" width="50" id="picture" hidden />
    </tr>
}
}
  $("#rd").click(function () {
                $('#picture').attr('src', '/Images/vt.png');
                var ps = $('#ps').val();
                alert(ps);
                $(picture).show();
   });
```

Comment: Because your generating invalid html with all the duplicate `id` attributes and using `.val()` will only return the value of the first element with `id="ps")`

Comment: And in any case a radio button is not appropriate for this. A radio button is for selecting one from many and that clearly not your intention. Just use a button or checkbox (not using a html helper) and add the value as a `data-` attribute and delete the hidden input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are rendering multiple elements with same id which is the reason it is not working, it will always fire event for just first item it finds in the DOM with that id.

Change it to class and add click event on class selector:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Position, new {@class="ps" })
@Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem => item.isCandidate, item.CandId, new { @class="rd",name="rd"})
<img src="" height="50" width="50" class="picture"/>
```

and in js:

```
$(".rd").click(function () {
  var picture = $(this).closest("tr").find('.picture').attr('src', '/Images/vt.png');
  var ps = $(this).closest("tr").find('.ps').val();
  $(picture).show();
});
```

Comment: glad it helped. never add multiple elements with same id in html